# SQLite 3 Error when using parameter string, but not when implicitly typed

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

I have a snippet of code from my python 2.7 program:

`cur.execute("UPDATE echo SET ? = ? WHERE ID = ?", (cur_class, fdate, ID,))`

that when run, keeps throwing the following error:

`sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error`

The program is supposed to insert today's date, into the class column that matches the student ID supplied. If I remove the first "?" like so and hard code the parameter:

`cur.execute("UPDATE echo SET math = ? WHERE ID = ?", (fdate, ID,))`

everything works just fine. I've googled all over the place and haven't found anything that works yet so I'm throwing out a lifeline.
I've tried single quotes, double quotes, with and without parenthesis and a few other things I can't remember now. So far nothing works other than hard coding that first parameter which is really inconvenient.

As a troubleshooting step I had my program print the type() of each of the variables and they're all strings. The data type of the the cur_class field is VARCHAR, fdate is DATE, and ID is VARCHAR.

Comment: You can't use a parameter for a table or column name. Those have to be known when the SQL statement is compiled to sqlite's internal bytecode, not when it's actually executed, which means they have to be hardcoded into the query.

Comment: @Shawn thanks for the heads up, I'm still relatively new to sqlite so I overlooked that. I solved the problem with an extra line of code (below)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the tip from @Shawn earlier I solved the issue with the following code and it works great:

`sqlcommand = "UPDATE echo SET " + cur_class + " = " + fdate + " WHERE ID = " + ID`
`cur.execute(sqlcommand)`

This way python does the heavy lifting and constructs my string with all the variables expanded, then has the db execute the properly formatted SQL command.